# bjam link against boost-system

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

What is the correct/portable way to link against the boost-system library in a bjam project?

If an example Jamroot.jam file could be posted that would be great.

Comment: Boost.FileSystem itself uses Boost.System; have you looked at its Jamfile for reference?

Answer (score 1):

```
use-project /boost : /path/to/boost ;
exe thing : thing.cpp /boost//system ;
```